# Find $P(X+Y<1/2)$.

Tags: probability, random-variables

X and Y are continuous random variables uniformly distributed on the region consisting of two unit squares. The first square is located in the first quadrant, $0<x<1$ and $0<y<1$. The second square is located in the third quadrant, $-1<x<0$ and $-1<y<0$. Find $P(X+Y<1/2)$.

I thought P(X+Y<1/2) equaled the area of the second unit square in the third quadrant plus the area of the triangle from $0<x<1/2$ and $0<y<1/2$ in the first unit square.
Such that $P(X+Y<1/2) = 1 + (1/2)(1/2)^2$. However, my professor said my drawing was correct but that the answer is 1/2.

Could someone please help me see where I went wrong?

Comment: You do realize that the probability you calculated is in fact more than 1?

Comment: Oh.. right... oops!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The densities at each point on the support would be $\frac12$

To compute the probability distribution, we just have to multiply the density by the area,

$$P(X+Y < \frac12)=\frac12 (1+(1/2)(1/2)^2)$$

This number should be bigger than $\frac12$ as the second square alone would have satisfied the condition.

Comment: Great answer, thank you very much! To find f(x,y) did you set a double integral equal to 1 or was it more intuitive?

Comment: For uniform distribution, the densities over the support should be $1$ over the area as they need to be integrate to be $1$.

Comment: Yes, that's neat...+1